# Зависимость поля от чекбокса! Нужно что бы поле Ответ СБ было свободным, но при нажатии чекбокса, оно становилось обязательным для заполнения

Tags: javascript, php

```
 print '<div class="input_title">Ответ С.Б.</div>';
                                print '<input type="text" name="'.$banks_list['bank_code'].'_comment_sb" id="comment_sb" placeholder="Введите комментарий" value="'.$bank_trades['comment_sb'].'" class="input"/>';
                                print '<div style="display: inline-flex;"><input type="checkbox" id="disban" name="'.$banks_list['bank_code'].'_disban" value="" style="margin-right: 10px;"/><div>Не отправлять заявки в банк</div></div>';
                                print '<input type="text" id="disinfo" name="'.$banks_list['bank_code'].'_disinfo" placeholder="Информация для партнёра" style="display: none" value="" class="input" />';




  $('#disban').live('click', function(){
        info =$(this).parent().next();
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            info.show();
        } else {
            info.hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код обработчика события:

```
$('#disban')
.live('click', function (ev){
    var info = $(this).parent().next();
    var repsb = $(this).parent().prev();
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
      repsb.prop('required', true);
      info.show();
  } else {
      info.hide();
      repsb.removeAttr('required', false);
  }
});
```

**Обновлено 3!**

Comment: в таком случае, получатся что поле все равно нужно заполнять при нажатом и не нажатом чекбоксе

Comment: так, простите, подставил required и верхнее поле стало обязательным, но, нужно сделать что бы не выплывающее поле было обязательным для заполнения, а то которое "ответ СБ"

Comment: @Вася, обновил ответ

Comment: а так не выходит всплывающее окно, и все равно поле не стало обязательным(((

Comment: @Вася, первый ```<input type="text" ... /> должен быть  с изменяемым атрибутом `required`? Так?

Comment: jigius, да все верно

Comment: получается, если я ввожу Ваш код, выплывающее поле при нажатии checkbox-а, не выплывает, а в независимости от нажатого или не нажатого checkbox-а, первый input не становится обязательным.

Comment: Вооооот, теперь все работает, СПАСИБО ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ, а то я уже все голову сломал как это сделать

Comment: @Вася, проверьте еще раз. Я селектор поменял на ```var repsb = $(this).parent().prev();```  - предыдущий неверный был - div выбирал (((

Comment: да, все работает, не человек, человечище, я просто начинающий только((